# mat-table won't get filled with data from restservice

Tags: html, angular, typescript, rest, angular-material

I am getting an array from my restservice. This is working and some information of the response I am printing on the page. But strangely I cannot fill my mat-table and I don't know why.The mat-table was working before, I am just not putting the data in it the right way. Every help will be appreciated.

table-paginator-component.ts:

```js
import {Component, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {MatPaginator} from '@angular/material/paginator';
import {MatTableDataSource} from '@angular/material/table';
import {HttpService} from '../http.service';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import {AreaCode} from '../models/areacode';


@Component({
  // tslint:disable-next-line: component-selector
  selector: 'table-paginator',
  styleUrls: ['table-paginator.component.css'],
  templateUrl: 'table-paginator.component.html',
})
export class TablePaginatorComponent implements OnInit {
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['standort', 'stammnummer', 'bereich'];


  products = [];


  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<any>(this.products);

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {
    this.getAreaCodes();
  }

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, {static: true}) paginator: MatPaginator;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
  }

  getAreaCodes() {






  this.httpClient.get('http://localhost:8080/phonenumbersmanagement/api/v1/areacodes/all')
.subscribe((res: 
any[]) => {
      console.log(res);
      this.products = res;
    });
  }

}
```

table-paginator.component.html:

```html
<!-- <button (click)="getAreaCodes2()">GET /productss</button> -->

<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let product of products" >
-- id: {{product.id}}
-- name: {{product.title}}
-- base: {{product.base}}
  </li>
</ul> 

<div class="mat-elevation-z8">


<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">

  <!-- Position Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="standort">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Standort </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.title}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Name Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="stammnummer">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Stammnummer </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.title}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Weight Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="bereich">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Bereich </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.title}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>

<mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
</div>
```

Current Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with `this.products = res;
this.datasource.data = res;`

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me. Could you explain why my code is not working and why yours is working?

Answer (score 1):

Change your getAreaCodes method like below,

```
getAreaCodes() {
  this.httpClient.get('http://localhost:8080/phonenumbersmanagement/api/v1/areacodes/all')
    .subscribe((res: any[]) => {
      this.products = res;
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(res);
    });
}
```

Update your mat-paginator with length as like property binding.

```
<mat-paginator [length]="products.length" [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
```

Comment: The table will get filled but the table says there are 0 of 0 data entries. Something is missing

Comment: Thank you, but the paginator is not working. And I am trying to understand this. If I click on 5 datasets per row or 10, still all datarows will be shown. But the solution of Aakash Bumiya works perfectly. I just don't understand why. Maybe you do?

Comment: This answer helped me out. Thanks for your approach.

Comment: Getting can't set properties of undefined setting paginator

Answer (score 0):

This thing worked for me. import table from angular/material and create an 
instance of it using viewchild. get your user data and set `displayedColumns` in `ngOnInit()`, In `ngAfterContentChecked()` you need to create `MatTableDataSource` instance and set this instance to `table.dataSource` in `ngAfterViewInit()` check below

```
import { MatTable, MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';

export class GetUserComponent implements OnInit {

@ViewChild(MatTable, {static:false}) table: MatTable<any>;
dataSource :any;


constructor(private appService:AppService){}

 ngOnInit() {
      this.appService.getUsers().subscribe(data => {
       this.userData= data;
      });
     this.displayedColumns = ['select','title','content'];
 }
 ngAfterViewInit() {

   this.table.dataSource = this.dataSource;
 }
 ngAfterContentChecked(){
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource (this.userData);
  }
}
```

you can check my stackblitz here 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamicexamples

Answer (score 0):

I think that, when you receive data from api and add result value to products variable then datasource variable dont update.

Try to use products variable on html table tag-> [dataSource]="products"